# How to fix broken libstdc++6, which also breaks apt

Tags: apt, package-management, dpkg, dependencies

I seem to have messed up something with a manual `gcc` update sometime in the past, which didn't become a problem until today, when I upgraded from 14.04 to 16.04. Namely, the system seems to think that the `libstdc++6` version is OK, while `apt` (and many other programs) complain it isn't (because the shared library is actually in the wrong version):

```
sudo apt-get install --fix-broken --fix-missing
apt-get: relocation error: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libapt-pkg.so.5.0: symbol _ZNKSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEE7compareERKS4_, version GLIBCXX_3.4.21 not defined in file libstdc++.so.6 with link time reference
```

The system doesn't even start a graphical mode, the above output was obtained using a non-graphical console (using `Ctrl-Alt-F6`), and `apt` itself is completely unusable, so I can't just do something like a reinstall.

How can I fix and reinstall these packages, when the program I'm using for managing them itself is affected and unusable?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

At first, I was able to get a graphical login shell by manually copying [`libstdc++.so.6.0.21`](http://packages.ubuntu.com/xenial/amd64/libstdc++6/filelist) into its place from a Live USB stick, and creating a link to it from `libstdc++.so.6`. I used this exact version because it seems to be the default for Ubuntu 16.04 and also contains the "21" mentioned in the error message ("version GLIBCXX_3.4.21").

While this seemed to satisfy the graphics stack, the same errors remained with `apt` and other programs depending on libstdc++6. After some trying, I could resolve the whole thing with the following steps, using `dpkg` to manually (un)install things:

- Download the deb files in the right versions for 16.04:

  ```
  wget http://mirrors.kernel.org/ubuntu/pool/main/a/apt/apt_1.2.10ubuntu1_amd64.deb http://mirrors.kernel.org/ubuntu/pool/main/g/gcc-5/libstdc++6_5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.4_amd64.deb
  ```
- Removing this specific version, which blocked installing the correct libstdc++6:

  ```
  sudo dpkg --force-depends -r libstdc++6:i386
  ```
- Then install the "good" version from the files:

  ```
  sudo dpkg -i libstdc++6_5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.4_amd64.deb apt_1.2.10ubuntu1_amd64.deb
  ```
- And finally, fix the mess I left while updating and trying things out:

  ```
  sudo apt-get install -f
  ```

Comment: Saved my life !

Comment: for 32bit. `wget http://mirrors.edge.kernel.org/ubuntu/pool/main/a/apt/apt_1.2.10ubuntu1_i386.deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/g/gcc-5/libstdc++6_5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.10_i386.deb` then `sudo dpkg --force-depends -r libstdc++6:i386` then `sudo dpkg -i libstdc++6_5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.10_i386.deb apt_1.2.10ubuntu1_i386.deb `

Comment: For Ubuntu 18.04.1 
https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic/amd64/libstdc++6/download

had similar problem:
sudo apt-get update
apt-get: error while loading shared libraries: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6: invalid ELF header