# Install GDBM when apt is not working

Tags: apt, package-management, python, dpkg, update-manager

I am trying to update my 16.04 to the latest 18.10. But this caused a relocation error with the package `libapt-pkg.so`. This naturally makes my apt useless. To overcome that I am following the advice given [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/818752/how-to-fix-broken-libstdc6-which-also-breaks-apt) to force install the package. However when I run `dpkg -i` it says that GDBM is not found. Naturally I cannot install GDBM because my apt is not working. How to overcome this.

Comment: can you please post the error message.

Comment: @g_p apt-get: relocation error: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libapt-private.so.0.0: symbol _ZN9pkgSystem9LockInnerEv version APTPKG_5.0 not defined in file libapt-pkg.so.5.0 with link time reference